# Update kernel for WSL Ubuntu

Tags: kernel, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed a new kernel in WSL v2 running inside Windows 10.
The new kernel is 6.2, old is 5.15. There is only the 6.2 version in `/boot`. I rebooted the machine.
Why does it still boot on told 5.15? How do I change it to the new kernel?

```
root@DESKTOP:/#ls boot/
System.map-6.2.0-34-generic  config-6.2.0-34-generic  grub  initrd.img  
initrd.img-6.2.0-34-generic  initrd.img.old  vmlinuz  vmlinuz-6.2.0-34-generic  vmlinuz.old



root@DESKTOP:/#uname -rsa
Linux DESKTOP 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP 
Fri Jan 27 02:56:13 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: In WSL2, you're just running a container in a VM set up by Windows. You can try updating the kernel all you want in the container, but the VM is still going to use what it is configured to use.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way: This is a list of all supported WSL2 kernels and their source. I can upgrade to any kernel from listed here.
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel/releases